# Use IPointerEnterHandler with bool function?

Tags: unity, gui

Im trying to use mouse pointer to detect any UI element on my canvas. when pointer enter any UI element, UI_active set true, else UI_active set false. Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;// Required when using Event data.

public class UI_AVATAR : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler {

public bool  UI_active;

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("The cursor entered the selectable UI element.");
    print(eventData.currentInputModule.name);
    print(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only care about whether the pointer is over *any* button, not whether it's over a specific button, then I think the method you want is:

```
EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject();
```

[IsPointerOverGameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) returns true if (the given) mouse cursor / finger is over any event system object in your UI, serving the role of your `UI_active` variable.